# Uploading a file along with post data in android to php server

Tags: php, android, httpurlconnection

I am working on a project where I need to upload files to a remote server. I also need to send some other POST Parameters along with the file. Following is the code on the android side:

```
try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        URL url = new URL(UPLOAD_URL);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("myFile", fileName);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myFile\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        Log.i("Huzza", "Initial .available : " + bytesAvailable);

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        fileInputStream.close();

        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();
        } catch (IOException ioex) {
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }else {
        return "Could not upload";
    }
```

The file is successfully uploaded through this code. I need to know how do I send other POST Parameters along with it. Thanks.

Comment: `conn.setRequestProperty("myFile", fileName);` So the file name arrived? Can you omit this statement? I think you can.

Comment: Yes, I checked. This statement can be omitted. But the original question remains. How to send POST strings along with the file. @greenapps

Comment: Well you can send them between boundaries also. Almost the same as with the file. Examples many on this site.

Comment: Can you please give an example for the same?

Comment: I simply have no idea of doing it. Kindly post an example @greenapps

Comment: As i said: there are many examples on this site. Google for boundary.

Comment: Are you trying to post a link when you say 'this site', since I am not able to see any referred site. @greenapps

Comment: @greenapps sir I really need help on this one. I would really appreciate if you could post me an example. Your comment seems to have no link to the 'site'